# C# Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown

Tags: c#

My code :

```
public bool key;
private void KeySelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        switch (cb.Text)
        {
            case "F1":
                key = System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.F1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
```

The code above is for `Combobox Events TextChanged`. And now I have a timer that I want to catch the key. The code is :

```
private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (key == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success !")
        }
    }
```

But the problem is the code is not working. When I pressed F1 key nothing show up.

When I change the `Timer` code to this :

```
    private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool key = System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.F1);
        if (key == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success !")
        }
    }
```

its working.

Now, My questions are how can I build the timer to check the key from combobox text changed. While main timer are ticking and I pressed the key the messagebox should show.(I mean how can I fix that code to be working)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try to explain the problem you are trying to solve. I'm not sure you have the right approach. To answer your question, I think the key is no longer pressed when you enter the KeySelect method. Can't you just use the KeyDown event on the ComboBox? The eventargs will contain the pressed key.

Comment: The problem that I am trying to solve is I have all of the keyboard key in the Combobox Events TextChanged. And I want the timer to catch the key that I choose and pressed. Like in the code but the problem is when I declared a "key" out side the timer it will not working. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KeySelect` method fires, when the user changes the selected item of the combobox. At this time, you query if the key (F1) is pressed, which of course is not pressed. So you have to save the selected keyboard key in a class member when changing the combobox, and then in your timer handler you have to ask the system if this key is pressed at the moment.

So instead of `public bool key;` you have to save `pubic Key key` as class member and in your KeySelect method you set something like

```
switch (cb.Text)
    {
        case "F1":
            key = System.Windows.Input.Key.F1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
```

and then in your timer handler you check:

```
private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success !")
    }
}
```

Comment: it says "Cannot convert from bool to system.windows.input.key" . how can I save public key key?

Comment: in which line do you get this error?. if you do not use "usings" then you have to declare "public System.Windows.Input.Key key" instead of "public bool key"